# Toggling between Grouping and non grouping of datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, toggle, groupstyle

I have currently populated a datagrid with certain amount of rows and grouped the rows based on department.
So ,all I can see in my output is a "Department-based Grouped Datagrid".

Is it possible to toggle between grouping and non grouping of datagrid rows ?

For Example : If a user doesnt wants to see records based on groups, he'll click on radiobutton and datagrid will populate rows without grouping and vice-versa.

Thanks in advance.

Here is sample code inside DataGrid.GroupStyle :

```
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander Margin="15 0 0 0" IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock  Foreground="white" Text="{Binding Path=emp}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
                                                <TextBlock  Foreground="white" Text="{Binding Path=empCount}" Margin="10 0 3 0"/>
                                                <TextBlock  Foreground="white" Text="emps"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Clean or Add the GroupDescriptions based on toggle.

Comment: My sample code doesnt have any GroupDescriptions . . So how do I do then ?

Comment: Use GroupDescriptions then.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is old, but I might as well answer.

The edit you need to do are not in your GroupStyle but in the code of your ViewModel. You probably bind your listview ItemSource to an ObservableCollection<>. Internally A view of your collection is made, and this collectionView is the one that is actually bound to your ListView. You can explicitly obtain that view in this way:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<T> HeldCollection{ get; set; }


        #region properties for the view
        CollectionView _HeldView;
        public CollectionView HeldView
        {
            get
            {
                if (_HeldView == null)
                {
                    _HeldView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(HeldCollection);
                    //_HeldView.GroupDescriptions.Add(GroupDescription);
                }
                return _HeldView;
            }
        }
```

You can then edit the GroupDescription since it is a property of the CollectionView, for example in response to a button toggle.